# Can I re-publish links extracted from Stack Exchange data dumps under the public domain?

Tags: discussion, data-dump, copyright, licensing

[After looking around and finding none](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270888/is-there-a-mapping-from-stack-overflow-tags-to-wikipedia-wikidata-entities), I'm trying to link as many Stack Exchange tags as possible to [WikiData](http://wikidata.org) entities.  My ultimate goal is to automatically categorize tags on Stack Overflow based on categories in Wikipedia.

I've gone through the steps to create a [property on WikiData](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1482) to hold URLs of equivalent Stack Exchange tags on WikiData entities.  I've manually added [a few instances of tags to entities](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3AWhatLinksHere&target=Property%3AP1482&namespace=0).  Now I'd like to add a few thousand more [via a bot](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/User:StackerBot), but before I do, I want to make sure I properly follow the license on Stack Exchange data.

The best way I could think of to seed the entity/tag links was to look at the Stack Overflow tag wikis.  From the May data dump I have extracted a few thousand links to Wikipedia articles found in the Stack Overflow tag wikis.  I've manually reviewed them to ensure an approximate one-to-one relationship between the tags and the Wikipedia articles.  I'm very confident in the quality of the links, and now I want to add them to WikiData.

The Stack Exchange data in totality is [CC-by-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) licensed. WikiData is [CC0/Public Domain](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/).  Would the nature of the extraction I've done (pulling out just the links to Wikipedia articles and converting them to WikiData entities) be transformative enough to permit me to use the fair use exemption to publish the derived data under the public domain suitable for use in WikiData?  Or do I need to seek special permission from Stack Exchange?

Or do I have to ask people to construct the links by hand?